# Implementing ciphertext stealing with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes

I'm using OpenSSL's EVP_* API to implement AES encryption in CBC mode.

I'm trying to implement ciphertext stealing to keep the encrypted text the same length as the plain text. I found a method to switch off padding (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding()), but that doesn't seem to switch on ciphertext stealing instead of padding.

Does anyone have an example howto do ciphertext stealing ?

Comment: Although it is normally frowned upon to create your own crypto, you might want to implement it yourself if you don't get a good answer (it might not be included in the openssl libs, sometimes hard to tell). These kind of modes are normally pretty easy to implement. Beware that any decryption without integrity protection is a bit dangerous though.

Comment: @owlstead: Wikipedia mentions a way to implement ciphertext stealing with a standard CBC engine, but if I can, I'd rather use something that already has been tested than create my own.

Comment: It should be preferred of course, but OpenSSL is not known to support each and every mode, so if you cannot easily find it on the internet, there is a big chance you won't get an answer. You might use CTR mode instead, it is a stream cipher mode for block ciphers, and does not require padding either.

Comment: @owlstead: CTR requires unique IVs to be secure, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [patch](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=1482&user=guest&pass=guest) for OpenSSL from 2007 that implements chiphertext stealing. It hasn't been included, but there was no problem including the code into my application.